# Path.GetDirectoryName changes in .NET Framework 4.6.2

Tags: c#, .net

Recently I updated my unit test project from .NET 4.5.1 to a higher version. When you update .net to 4.6.2 and higher there are changes in Path.GetDirectoryName behavior. It is known that in 4.6.2 version it become stricter, not allowing uri syntax anymore. But in my case I observe that it becomes LESS strict in some cases. The wrong path "/:\test\temp.txt" which caused an exception before now passes. Is this also a known issue or are there reasons for it?

```
using System.IO;
...
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName("/:\\test\\temp.txt");
// .net 4.6.1: throws ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.
// .net 4.6.2 and above: dir = \:\test
```

Comment: [Path.GetDirectoryName and Path.GetPathRoot don't work with URIs when you target the .NET Framework 4.6.2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3181958) might help

Comment: Yes, I read this link. But in my case the path which didn't work before does.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and the results you are seeing for those inputs from 4.5.1 and 4.6.2.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/07/30/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10/